# Variable output from method

Tags: java, methods

Hey everyone,

```
public void bubbleSort(boolean radioValue, Integer[] bubbleArray) {
    //declare and initialize variables
    int tempVar = 0;
    int swappedValue = 0;
    int loopExecuted = 0;
    int comparisonMade = 0;

    //if radioValue is true run this if statement
    if (radioValue) {
        //declare boolean true and run while statement as long as boolean is true
        //increase loopExecuted
        boolean swapped = true;
        while (swapped) {
            loopExecuted++;

            //declare boolean as false and run for loop to go over array
            swapped = false;
            for (int i = 1; i < bubbleArray.length; i++) {
                //declare and intialize variable and increase loopExecuted and comparisonMade
                int temp = 0;
                loopExecuted++;
                comparisonMade++;

                //if bubbleArray i-1 is greater than bubbleArray i run this if statement
                if (bubbleArray[i - 1] > bubbleArray[i]) {

                    //make temp value bubbleArray i-1
                    //since bubbleArray i is greater than bubbleArray i-1 swap the values
                    //bubbleArray i is now temp which is bubbleArray i-1
                    //make boolean true and increase swappedValue counter
                    temp = bubbleArray[i - 1];
                    bubbleArray[i - 1] = bubbleArray[i];
                    bubbleArray[i] = temp;
                    swapped = true;
                    swappedValue++;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    //output the stats for bubble sort
    outputArea.append("Bubble Sort \n"
            + "Number of the loop was executed:" + loopExecuted + "\n Number of times a comparison was made" + comparisonMade
            + "\n Number of times a value was shifted" + swappedValue);

}
```

My question is, Is there someway for me to pass the variables of tempVar,swappedValue,loopExecuted, and comparisonMade to another method?
So for example, at the end of the bubbleSort method I have a line of code that outputs all these variables, but instead, I want it so that I have a method that does that instead of that line of code. This is mainly because I have more than one sorting algorithm and just want to streamline everything.

Comment: It's the same as passing `radioValue` and `bubbleArray` to `bubbleSort` method..

Comment: Just make a function that receives the variables and prints them on screen? I'm not sure what is it you're having trouble with

Answer (score 0):

Try making a class like this:

```
class BubbleSortParams{
    private int loopExecuted = 0;
    private int swappedValue = 0;
    private int comparisonMade = 0;
    int getLoopExecuted() {
        return loopExecuted;
    }
    void setLoopExecuted(int loopExecuted) {
        this.loopExecuted = loopExecuted;
    }
    int getSwappedValue() {
        return swappedValue;
    }
    void setSwappedValue(int swappedValue) {
        this.swappedValue = swappedValue;
    }
    int getComparisonMade() {
        return comparisonMade;
    }
    void setComparisonMade(int comparisonMade) {
        this.comparisonMade = comparisonMade;
    }
}
```

Then instead of printing their value, make the return type of your bubble sort method `BubbleSortParams` and just return an object of that type at the end of your method. Like this:

```
public BubbleSortParams bubbleSort(boolean radioValue, Integer[] bubbleArray) {
    //declare and initialize variables
    int tempVar = 0;
    int swappedValue = 0;
    int loopExecuted = 0;
    int comparisonMade = 0;

    //if radioValue is true run this if statement
    if (radioValue) {
        //declare boolean true and run while statement as long as boolean is true
        //increase loopExecuted
        boolean swapped = true;
        while (swapped) {
            loopExecuted++;

            //declare boolean as false and run for loop to go over array
            swapped = false;
            for (int i = 1; i < bubbleArray.length; i++) {
                //declare and intialize variable and increase loopExecuted and comparisonMade
                int temp = 0;
                loopExecuted++;
                comparisonMade++;

                //if bubbleArray i-1 is greater than bubbleArray i run this if statement
                if (bubbleArray[i - 1] > bubbleArray[i]) {

                    //make temp value bubbleArray i-1
                    //since bubbleArray i is greater than bubbleArray i-1 swap the values
                    //bubbleArray i is now temp which is bubbleArray i-1
                    //make boolean true and increase swappedValue counter
                    temp = bubbleArray[i - 1];
                    bubbleArray[i - 1] = bubbleArray[i];
                    bubbleArray[i] = temp;
                    swapped = true;
                    swappedValue++;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    BubbleSortParams bsp = new BubbleSortParams();
    bsp.setComparisonMade(comparisonMade);
    bsp.setLoopExecuted(loopExecuted);
    bsp.setSwappedValue(swappedValue);
    return bsp;

}
```

Now you can do whatever you want with the variables in a different method! Such as the following:

```
public void myMethod(BubbleSortParams bsp) {
    //now you can access the parameters from your other method
    int swappedValue = bsp.getSwappedValue();
    int loopExecuted = bsp.getLoopExecuted();
    int comparisonMade = bsp.getComparisonMade();
    //do whatever you want with the variables now!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a private method like

```
private void printStuff (int tempVar,int swappedValue,int loopExecuted,int comparisonMade){

    // print it how ever you want

}
```